# Cannot run generate bundler/setup (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm running OS X, 10.11.2 (15C50), with rvm 1.26.11, ruby 2.3.0p0 and gem 2.5.1.
If I try to run `rails g controller welcome` or any other generate command, I get the following error.

I've done a rvm implode, installed ruby, rails, bundler from scratch. Created a new app, the problem remains.

```
% rails g controller welcome                                                                                                      
/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
    from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/username/Projects/tweener-frontend/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-1.6.1/lib/spring/commands.rb:33:in `<module:Spring>'
    from /Users/username/Projects/tweener-frontend/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-1.6.1/lib/spring/commands.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/username/Projects/tweener-frontend/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-1.6.1/lib/spring/application.rb:77:in `preload'
    from /Users/username/Projects/tweener-frontend/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-1.6.1/lib/spring/application.rb:143:in `serve'
    from /Users/username/Projects/tweener-frontend/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-1.6.1/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
    from /Users/username/Projects/tweener-frontend/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-1.6.1/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
    from /Users/username/Projects/tweener-frontend/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-1.6.1/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
    from /Users/username/Projects/tweener-frontend/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-1.6.1/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Comment: `bundle install && bundle exec rails g controller welcome ` try this?

Comment: check `echo $GEM_PATH` this sometime happen for Ruby's load_path is different from GEM_PATH for multi ruby installation ....Please also post `gem env`

Comment: Here is the GEM path `/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@tweener-frontend:/Users/jjennings/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global`

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and I did the following to fix the issue:

```
bundle install --binstubs
```

Try this first and then try running:

```
bundle exec rails g controller welcome
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: binstubs didn't help. I got this

`Looks like your app's ./bin/rails is a stub that was generated by Bundler.

In Rails 4, your app's bin/ directory contains executables that are versioned
like any other source code, rather than stubs that are generated on demand.

Here's how to upgrade:

  bundle config --delete bin    # Turn off Bundler's stub generator
  rake rails:update:bin         # Use the new Rails 4 executables`

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work for me either. Looks like all it did was a) generate a bunch of unwanted binstubs, and b) remove all of the spring related stuff. That did, however, key me it to the fact that I had spring running already (using the 2.2.3 instance of my app). I stopped that, reran `bin/rails s` and was up and running.

Answer (score 0):

So `bundle exec rails s` seems to be the fix.
I guess I need to understand why I need to use bundle exec instead of just `rails s`. Time to read the manual :)

Thanks everyone